# Can the "Trashbox" directory created in Ubuntu backup be cleared?

Tags: backup

I've been backing up both an Ubuntu and a Windows computer to a 4TB Buffalo network storage device for some years, but it is now full and the Ubuntu backup program is saying the backups are failing because of lack of space.

The network storage device has a "Computer Backups" directory that has 426 GB of files.

There is also a "trashbox" directory that also contains 3.6 TB of files all apparently backup data (they start with "duplicity_inc" and end in ".gpg" filenames).

Can this "trashbox" directory be cleared out? Or would that corrupt the backups?

Thank you!

Comment: Who (or what) moved the duplicity backups into the trash directory? If it was done by Duplicity itself, you should be good. If it was done by a person, then it could result in a failed backup restoration 

Comment: Thanks, matigo. The trashbox appears  to be created by the network storage device, not Ubuntu or the Duplicity backup program.  I will go ahead and clear that out.